# Uber Ride Request Button Sample

Tags: android, uber-api

I am trying to run the Uber's Ride Request Button Sample that is available on Uber Developer website.

However, I ran into some error that I couldn't figure it out. I hope you guys can help.

Thanks,
CassL

SampleActivity.java

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RideRequestButtonCallback {

private static final String DROPOFF_ADDR = "One Embarcadero Center, San Francisco";
private static final Double DROPOFF_LAT = 37.795079;
private static final Double DROPOFF_LONG = -122.397805;
private static final String DROPOFF_NICK = "Embarcadero";
private static final String ERROR_LOG_TAG = "UberSDK-SampleActivity";
private static final String PICKUP_ADDR = "1455 Market Street, San Francisco";
private static final Double PICKUP_LAT = 37.775304;
private static final Double PICKUP_LONG = -122.417522;
private static final String PICKUP_NICK = "Uber HQ";
private static final String UBERX_PRODUCT_ID = "a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d";
private static final int WIDGET_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

private static final String CLIENT_ID = BuildConfig.CLIENT_ID;
private static final String SERVER_TOKEN = BuildConfig.SERVER_TOKEN;

private RideRequestButton blackButton;
private SessionConfiguration configuration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

    configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setServerToken(SERVER_TOKEN)
            .build();

    // Optional: to use the SDK in China, set the region property
    // See https://developer.uber.com/docs/china for more details.
    // configuration.setEndpointRegion(SessionConfiguration.EndpointRegion.CHINA);

    validateConfiguration(configuration);
    ServerTokenSession session = new ServerTokenSession(configuration);

    RideParameters rideParametersForProduct = new RideParameters.Builder()
            .setProductId(UBERX_PRODUCT_ID)
            .setPickupLocation(PICKUP_LAT, PICKUP_LONG, PICKUP_NICK, PICKUP_ADDR)
            .setDropoffLocation(DROPOFF_LAT, DROPOFF_LONG, DROPOFF_NICK, DROPOFF_ADDR)
            .build();

    // This button demonstrates deep-linking to the Uber app (default button behavior).
    blackButton = (RideRequestButton) findViewById(R.id.uber_button_black);
    blackButton.setRideParameters(rideParametersForProduct);
    blackButton.setSession(session);
    blackButton.setCallback(this);
    blackButton.loadRideInformation();

    RideParameters rideParametersCheapestProduct = new RideParameters.Builder()
            .setPickupLocation(PICKUP_LAT, PICKUP_LONG, PICKUP_NICK, PICKUP_ADDR)
            .setDropoffLocation(DROPOFF_LAT, DROPOFF_LONG, DROPOFF_NICK, DROPOFF_ADDR)
            .build();

    // This button demonstrates launching the RideRequestActivity (customized button behavior).
    // You can optionally setRideParameters for pre-filled pickup and dropoff locations.
    RideRequestButton uberButtonWhite = (RideRequestButton) findViewById(R.id.uber_button_white);
    RideRequestActivityBehavior rideRequestActivityBehavior = new RideRequestActivityBehavior(this,
            WIDGET_REQUEST_CODE, configuration);
    uberButtonWhite.setRequestBehavior(rideRequestActivityBehavior);
    uberButtonWhite.setRideParameters(rideParametersForProduct);
    uberButtonWhite.setSession(session);
    uberButtonWhite.loadRideInformation();
}

@Override
public void onRideInformationLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Estimates have been refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onError(ApiError apiError) {
    Toast.makeText(this, apiError.getClientErrors().get(0).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
    Log.e("SampleActivity", "Error obtaining Metadata", throwable);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == WIDGET_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED && data != null) {
        if (data.getSerializableExtra(RideRequestActivity.AUTHENTICATION_ERROR) != null) {
            AuthenticationError error = (AuthenticationError) data.getSerializableExtra(RideRequestActivity
                    .AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            Toast.makeText(SampleActivity.this, "Auth error " + error.name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(ERROR_LOG_TAG, "Error occurred during authentication: " + error.toString
                    ().toLowerCase());
        } else if (data.getSerializableExtra(RideRequestActivity.RIDE_REQUEST_ERROR) != null) {
            RideRequestViewError error = (RideRequestViewError) data.getSerializableExtra(RideRequestActivity
                    .RIDE_REQUEST_ERROR);
            Toast.makeText(SampleActivity.this, "RideRequest error " + error.name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(ERROR_LOG_TAG, "Error occurred in the Ride Request Widget: " + error.toString().toLowerCase());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    AccessTokenManager accessTokenManager = new AccessTokenManager(this);

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_clear) {
        accessTokenManager.removeAccessToken();
        Toast.makeText(this, "AccessToken cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_copy) {
        AccessToken accessToken = accessTokenManager.getAccessToken();

        String message = accessToken == null ? "No AccessToken stored" : "AccessToken copied to clipboard";
        if (accessToken != null) {
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("UberSampleAccessToken", accessToken.getToken());
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (id == R.id.action_refresh_meta_data) {
        blackButton.loadRideInformation();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Validates the local variables needed by the Uber SDK used in the sample project
 * @param configuration
 */
private void validateConfiguration(SessionConfiguration configuration) {
    String nullError = "%s must not be null";
    String sampleError = "Please update your %s in the gradle.properties of the project before " +
            "using the Uber SDK Sample app. For a more secure storage location, " +
            "please investigate storing in your user home gradle.properties ";

    checkNotNull(configuration, String.format(nullError, "SessionConfiguration"));
    checkNotNull(configuration.getClientId(), String.format(nullError, "Client ID"));
    checkNotNull(configuration.getServerToken(), String.format(nullError, "Server Token"));
    checkState(!configuration.getClientId().equals("wOUNMrsBNv_PspfQ16JldsPQx_ryzWpR"),
            String.format(sampleError, "Client ID"));
    checkState(!configuration.getRedirectUri().equals("QO-ROZAvU2BolTewBiwcH7Ww_50yGy8WEJPvYi7w"),
            String.format(sampleError, "Server Token"));
}
```

}

> Error:(48, 56) error: cannot find symbol variable CLIENT_ID
>   Error:(49, 59) error: cannot find symbol variable SERVER_TOKEN
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   07-23 22:05:31.366 15787-15801/? E/SarMIPIManager: handleMIPI:not match,use the default MIPI:454
>   07-23 22:05:31.481 6604-6604/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
>   07-23 22:05:31.481 6604-6604/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
>   07-23 22:05:31.486 6592-7340/? E/com.facebook.katana:MqttOperationManager: operation/add/duplicate; id=-1, name=PINGRESP
>   07-23 22:05:31.555 4334-5664/? E/native: do suspend false
>   07-23 22:05:32.651 18830-18840/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
>                                                     java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=16439, uid=10077 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
>                                                         at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:605)
>                                                         at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
>                                                         at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:211)
>                                                         at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
>                                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
>   07-23 22:05:32.724 16439-18825/? E/iu.UploadsManager: Insufficient permissions to process media
>                                                         java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=16439, uid=10077 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
>                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
>                                                             at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
>                                                             at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
>                                                             at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
>                                                             at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
>                                                             at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
>                                                             at ihc.a(PG:112)
>                                                             at com.google.android.libraries.social.autobackup.FingerprintScannerIntentService.onHandleIntent(PG:82)
>                                                             at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
>                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                             at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>   07-23 22:06:37.398 16178-16180/? E/QC-QMI: qmi_client [16178] 9d: failed to locate client data
>   07-23 22:06:37.402 3284-3284/? E/QC-QMI: qmuxd: RX on fd=19 returned error=0 errno[11:Try again]
>   07-23 22:06:37.417 3284-3284/? E/QC-QMI: QMUX qmux_client_id=9d not found in qmux client list, unable to remove
>   07-23 22:06:37.490 18878-18878/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13
>   07-23 22:07:50.711 16226-16226/? E/Spotify: [main@hgn$2:353] The application has been idle too long, stopping service
>   07-23 22:07:51.101 16226-16226/? E/Spotify: [main@service.SpotifyService:1100] Destroying service
>   07-23 22:07:53.433 16226-16226/? E/Spotify: [main@service.SpotifyService:34067] orbit stopped
>   07-23 22:08:56.584 6592-8800/? E/fb4a(:):GRAPHQL_QUERY_STRING: Trying to set unknown parameter 'first_notification_stories' on query 'DeltaNotificationsQuery'
>   07-23 22:08:57.056 6592-11826/? E/fb4a(:):GRAPHQL_QUERY_STRING: Trying to set unknown parameter 'first_notification_stories' on query 'DeltaNotificationsQuery'

Answer (score 1):

Did you edit your `gradle.properties` file? It should have your own CLIENT_ID and SERVER_TOKEN.